# python code explanation

Tags: python

I have been studying this code to generate random text:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from itertools import ifilter
from random import choice, randrange

def pairwise(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    last = next(it)
    for curr in it:
        yield last, curr
        last = curr

valid = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ')

def valid_pair((last, curr)):
    return last in valid and curr in valid

def make_markov(text):
    markov = defaultdict(Counter)
    lowercased = (c.lower() for c in text)
    for p, q in ifilter(valid_pair, pairwise(lowercased)):
        markov[p][q] += 1
    return markov

def genrandom(model, n):
    curr = choice(list(model))
    for i in xrange(n):
        yield curr
        if curr not in model:   # handle case where there is no known successor
            curr = choice(list(model))
        d = model[curr]
        target = randrange(sum(d.values()))
        cumulative = 0
        for curr, cnt in d.items():
            cumulative += cnt
            if cumulative > target:
                break

model = make_markov('The qui_.ck brown fox')
print ''.join(genrandom(model, 20))
```

However i am having trouble understanding the last bit, from target = randrange(sum(d.values())) onwards.
An explanation would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`target = randrange(sum(d.values()))`

`d.values()` Since model is a dictionary mapping letters to counter object, and a counter object is a dictionary, `d.values()` is a list of all the counts for each key in the dictionary (but doesn't return the keys). This means `sum(d.values())` will return the total of all the counts. `randrange()` choose  a value within [0, result) where result was the value of `sum(d.values())`.

`d.items()` returns key, value pairs for every item in the given counts dictionary. The code is trying to assign a probability to each letter and then choose a letter. If the counts are ('a', 5), ('b', 7), and ('c', 2), then the total number of counts is 14. The code chooses a random number between 0 and 13 (inclusive). If the result is in [0, 5), it will return 'a', if the result is in [5, 12), it will return 'b', and if the result is in [12, 14), it will return 'c'. The relative probabilities are determined by the width of those ranges, and the width of the ranges are determined by the counts determined in `make_markov`.

Comment: thank you so much, I understand now. But what about the last bit, isn't cumulative > target always true? what is the purpose of this statement? thanks for your help!

Comment: I would like to know if "if curr not in model: curr = choice(list(model))" has to be replaced with "while curr not in model: curr = choice(list(model))"? 
(I already raised this remark on this code once but I had o answer)

Comment: @jimifiki i don't know perhaps mlefavor does.

Comment: `cumulative > target` is usually not true. Using the numbers from my example, let's say `target` is assigned a value of 13. The first run through, cumulative will be assigned a value of 5, which is less than 13. Then it will be assigned a value of 12 (5 + 7 = 12). Finally, it will be assigned a value of 14, which is greater than `target`. The loop will stop, and `curr` will have the value of "c".

Comment: @jimifiki And yes, I think you're right. Failing more than once is not a likely situation for most texts, so that's probably why whoever wrote the code didn't notice. But it's still possible, and you'd need a `while` loop to prevent it.